# JS send message on correct input

Tags: javascript

I have a submit form that users are using to register:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" name="form" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="inputs" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="inputs" /><br />
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="inputs" /> 
 </div>
 <input type="submit" class="btn1" name="register" value="Register" />
</form>
```

The JS code is checking if the data is entered correctly. If the user enters incorrect date the JS code is showing a message. Now I want to show a message when the data is entered correctly. I tried to add a row like `if (errors.length < 0)` but this didn't work. The JS code sends me the message for the "correct input" and the message "Dont use symbols...\n".

How can I make this working?

Here is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var ck_name = /[A-Za-z0-9. ]{3,25}$/;
 var ck_email = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
 var ck_password =  /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,20}$/;

 function validate(form)
 {
 var name = form.name.value;
 var email = form.email.value;
 var password = form.password.value;

 var errors = [];

 if (!ck_name.test(name))
  {
  errors[errors.length] = "Name error! .";
  }

 if (!ck_email.test(email))
  {
  errors[errors.length] = "Email error! .";
  }

 if (!ck_password.test(password)) 
  {
  errors[errors.length] = "Password error!";
  }

 if (errors.length > 0) 
  {
  reportErrors(errors);
  return false;
  }

 return true;
 }

 function reportErrors(errors)
 {
 var msg = "Dont use symbols...\n";
 for (var i = 0; i<errors.length; i++) {
 var numError = i + 1;
 msg += "\n" + numError + ". " + errors[i];
 }
 alert(msg);
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors.length never won't be minor of 0. You must use equal (==). This works! :-)

**UPDATE**

```
if (errors.length == 0) {
 alert('Correct input');
}
```

That would be before the return true statement and after the if (errors.length > 0).

Comment: I also tried this. This is giving me the same result. I get the message for `(erros.length == 0)` and `"Dont use symbols...\n"`

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo in my answer, it's errors, not erros. Can you try with that change?

Comment: I dont get any message with the following code:
 `if (errors.length == 0) {
  errors[errors.length] = "Correct input";
  }`

Comment: Ok, I think that I understand you. You want to show a resume of what inputs are ok and wrong, don't you?

Comment: Currently the script is showing whats wrong. I want to show a "correct input" message if everything is correct and the script is posting.